# stopPropagation not working for KeyListener in YUI 2.7

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui, keylistener, propagation

I have created a new `YAHOO.util.KeyListener` to attach to a specific element and have also created another new `YAHOO.util.KeyListener` to attach to the entire document.  They are both associated with the <kbd>enter</kbd> key (keys:13).

In the handler function for the listener attached to the specific element, I have the following code:

```
            getDetailsLocalnameInput = function(e) {
                    getDetails(localnameInput.value);
                    YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(e);
                    YAHOO.util.Event.stopPropagation(e);
            };
```

Yet, the event from the keypress continues to propagate up to the key listener attached to the entire document.  I do not want the handler for the key listener attached to the entire document to get kicked off.  I am sure that both handlers are being called, but only want the handler attached to the specific element to run.

Is it correct to use `YAHOO.util.Event.stopPropagation` with `YAHOO.util.KeyListener`?

Is there a different way I should go about preventing the `keypress` event from being propagated?

I have also tried using the function `YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent` and setting `e.cancelBubble` with no success.

I have been testing all of this with Firefox 3.5.  I cannot get `stopPropagation()` to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 getDetailsLocalnameInput = function(e) {
     getDetails(localnameInput.value);

     if(window.event){
         e.cancelBubble=true;//In IE
     }else{
         evt.stopPropagation();//in Others
     }

     //YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(e);
     //YAHOO.util.Event.stopPropagation(e);
 };
```

Comment: `YAHOO.util.Event.stopPropagation` does the same thing. If that doesn’t work, neither will this.